# Testing specific gravity before bottling

Tags: specific-gravity, bottle, gravity-reading

I brewed a batch of beer about 3 weeks ago, and I was told to test the gravity prior to bottling to make sure it is ready.

My question is, will I do any harm by opening the fermentation bucket in order to collect a sample to test with. I do understand the principals around proper sanitisation.

I'm more concerned with introducing oxygen into the fermentation bucket if its not ready yet and I have to wait some more. Is that even something to worry about.

Thanks

Comment: I use my bottling wand through the airlock hole to get my samples. Spray the airlock with sanitizer before removal and before replacing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be introducing that much oxygen by opening the fermentation bucket to simply take a gravity sample, unless you go stirring it up or something.